# Relationship between monotonicity and bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

There is a theorem saying that if $f$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is of bounded variation. I am a bit confused about this claim. I am considering the following function, $f(x)=1$ if $x\in[a,b)$ and $f(b)=+\infty$. For any partition there is no positive number to bound $\Delta f_{k}$. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Does the theorem allow $f(b)\notin\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Hagen: Nothing mentioned, the theorem is in Apostol's analysis book (2nd edition, Thm 6.5) if it matters.

Comment: This theorem is for function with real values, so $\infty$ isn't allowed. You should think of bounded variation as "the length of the graph is bounded" so if it is monotonic then the graph is bounded by the length of the interval (times a constant). To not have bounded variation means the function has to oscillate wildly.

Comment: Well, if the theorem allows infinite values for $f$, change it so that it doesn't.